# Replace div tag contents using ajax call to controller method

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on a scenario which i am unable to achieve from long time.I have a table put inside `<div>` tag, whenever a user clicks on the `<tr> i.e. (row)` it sends the respective rowid as a parameter through ajax call to controller method.

I want to now render the respective method's (profile) view page with the whole  tag without refreshing the whole page.

My JS file :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tabl tr').click(function(){
        var val = $(this).attr('id');

      $.ajax({
           url: "/users/profile/",
           type: "GET",
           data: {'id': val}
  });
});
    });
```

Method :

```
def profile 
@prof = User.where(:id => params[:id])
 respond_to do |format|
  format.html
 end

end
```

view file ".html.erb" file

```
<html>
Hi there
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use success on your Ajax:

`$.ajax({
           url: "/users/profile/",
           type: "GET",
           data: {'id': val}
           success: function(response){
           //response is html written by the server
               $("#dividorwhatever").html(response) 
           }
});`

Comment: hi ..when adding the success method ..jquery stops responding..i mean even the `alert()` statement is not responding now.. If i remove success tag again ..it works..

Comment: maybe the `,` after `data:` I forgot it.